# RandomForestClassifier import

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I've installed Anaconda Python distribution with scikit-learn.
While importing RandomForestClassifier:

`from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier`

I have the following error:

`File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py", line 36, in <module>
    from . import _tree
ImportError: cannot import name _tree`

What the problem can be there?

Comment: try this: run `python -m site` and make sure there is no other python environment active other than  Anaconda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had the 64bit version of Anaconda and the 32bit sklearn.

Comment: how did you figure this? and how exactly did you fix it? i can't seem to figure my version and or how to update it..

Answer (score 4):

In sklearn version '0.18.1'

```
from sklearn.ensemble.forest import RandomForestClassifier
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by:

pip install -U scikit-learn