# How fix ImportError while improting RandamForestClassifier in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am getting following error. How can I resolve this?

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'RandamForestClassifier' from
'sklearn.ensemble'
(C:\Users\Devil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\__init__.py)
```

My code:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandamForestClassifier

print(RandamForestClassifier())
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29735766/randomforestclassifier-import) out

Comment: Maybe its because you have a typo at `RandamForestClassifier` which should be `RandomForestClassifier`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the random forest classification algorithm in scikit-learn you have to import it like this :

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
```

instead of :

```
    from sklearn.ensemble import RandamForestClassifier
```

so in easy words is : RandomForestClassifier not RandamForestClassifier